# How to get list of pull requests using API in GitLab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I would like to know if there is any API available from Gitlab to get all pull requests details for a repository.

I did search across gitlab documentation. But I couldn't find the proper API link.

Please suggest.

Best Regards
Gowtham

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are all the APIs you need in the [official documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/merge_requests.html). In Gitlab they are called **Merge requests**, not **Pull requests**, this is probably why you haven't found them

Comment: Yes. :) Thank you very much for the link.

Comment: Need one clarification. There is a field called "state". Can we say that, "merged" indicates pr accepted, "closed" indicates pr is rejected and "opened" indicates pending review? Please suggest.